# Enum as a Parameter in Dynamics AX

Tags: parameters, combobox, enums, axapta, x++

My report has a parameter which uses a base enum. The enum has 4 different options to choose when running the report. How do I insert an option which uses all 4 at once?

For example, I have an enum named Phone and it has 4 types: 1 = None, 2 = Home, 3 = Mobile, 4 = Work. In a drop down, how do I add option 5 = None+Home+Mobile+Work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add anoher enum with value All (see NoYes and NoYesAll enums as example)

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to solve your problem:

1. You can **alter** your Enum and add a new EnumValue with something like "All" (like AxCoder answer).
2. If you don't want (or you can't) modify this Enum you can copy it and **create a new** Enum with the New value. It will be your responsability to maintain both syncronized with future changes.
3. And you can **leave the Enum** without changes, and **add another parameter** to the report for you to know that the Enum value needs to be ignored by the Query (you have to code that beaviour, obviously)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the combo box on the form.
If you use the enum on the form as a ComboBox, make sure the AutoDeclare property is Yes.
Overwrite the Run() method of the form and add to the combo box after super.

Example:

```
public void run()
{
    super();
    YourComboBox.add("All");
}
```

On the modified method of the combo box, add the check for the word “All” by adding the code below before ret = super():

```
if (YourComboBox.getEditText() == "All")
{
        info("do your stuff"); //Add your code for the all selection here
}
```