# Hiding enum elements on runtime ax 2012

Tags: enums, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

If you have an enum which is used in more than one place, and at one of the places you need to hide one of the elements?

Comment: Technically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441422/how-to-hide-enum-values-on-a-combo-box-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding enum elements on runtime ax 2012

1.Override enter() on created ComboBox and write this code:

this.delete(enum2str(EnumType::Element1));
super();

Now run form and check.
Element1 is the element which you need to hide.

This worked for me.

Comment: This only works when the enum values that you want to remove are the last values. Otherwise the value no longer matches the selection. Example enum [0=A, 1=B, 2=C]. Deleting the last value 'C' will leave [0=A, 1=B], which is correct. Deleting 'A' will result in [0=B, 1=C] ==> the integer values no longer match the original enum.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using [SysFormEnumComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc603045(v=ax.50).aspx).

> The SysFormEnumComboBox class facilitates work with a form combo box control, representing an enumeration when only some of the enumeration values are allowed.

See [this blog post](http://kashperuk.blogspot.dk/2008/04/sysformenumcombobox-class-allowing-to.html) for an example.